# How to fix Disqus Invalid Argument 'thread' error?

Tags: ios, disqus

I'm implementing disqus in my app and i keep getting this:

```
{"code":2,"response":"Invalid argument, 'thread': Unable to find thread 'ident:https://www.idevice.ro/2015/04/27/ios-8-4-beta-2'"}
```

Where https://www.idevice.ro/2015/04/27/ios-8-4-beta-2 is the url where is disqus implemented.

This is the url i am calling.

```
http://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPosts.json?forum=ideviceromania&thread%3Aident=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Eidevice%2Ero%2F2015%2F04%2F27%2Fios-8-4-beta-2&api_secret=<<<API Secret>>>>
```

Can anybody explain what am i doing wrong or what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's old but I just crossed this and managed to solve it after a while. **The right way to do that is by using thread:link**, not thread:ident or thread and just providing post's the URL.

```
https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/set.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEI&forum=forum_short_name&thread:link=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpost_category%2Fpost_slug%2F
```

Tips:

- You can discover your forum_short_name by looking at your "disqus_shortname" variable on your site.
- Once you get the result, you won't be seeing a "comments" value returned on your json, the number you're looking after is on "posts".

Hope this helps someone else!